# Expand hidden content in newly expanded div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have a lot of content that I am using in an FAQ type setup. When a user clicks on any number of links it will expand the section and reveal a list of items which they themselves can be expanded too. What I am trying to accomplish is to have some of these list items expand when the FAQ div is toggled.

So the user clicks on the link that expands the list of items and the focus is set to the exact item content that goes with that link. Basically, like a hyperlink anchor would do only all of this content is on one page and there is a slideToggle followed by another slide toggle.

I made a fiddle of what I am trying to accomplish here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2AgT9/1/)

```
<h2>If you want to know more information about this exact item <a href="#" id="clicke">click  here!</a>
</h2>

<div id="myHiddenContent" style="display:none">
<li id="info-block-one">
<dl>
    <dt>
        <a aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" href="#contentBlock" id="infoLink">
            <strong>Info block one</strong></a>
    </dt>
    <dd tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" role="region" style="display: block;">
        <p class="answer" id="contentBlock" style="display:none">Info Block Answer</p>       
    </dd>
</dl>
</li>
```

```
$( "#infoLink" ).click(function() {
$( "#contentBlock" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
});
 });
$( "#clicke" ).click(function() {
$( "#myHiddenContent" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like below:

```
$( "#infoLink" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("dd").children("#contentBlock").slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
});
$( "#clicke" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("#myHiddenContent").slideToggle( "slow", function() {});
});
```

Comment: I tried it here and still the same behavior. I think I need to bind the one click handler to both toggles so I'll try that. Thanks though. http://jsfiddle.net/2AgT9/3/